# Do I have to roll to maintain concentration if a target other than me who is affected by my concentration spell takes damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, invisibility, concentration

We had a little puzzling situation during the last session of our group (I'm DMing here), and would like an approbation/rebuttal on the rule interpretation:

The Arcane Trickster of the team cast *invisibility* on himself and another member of the party. The group is then on the receiving side of a *fireball*. The trickster takes no damage, no concentration roll, so the spell hold. The invisible friend *does* take damage. Since he's not the one concentrating, the spell also hold for him.

Am I right on the interpretation?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, how does the rogue cast invisibility on two targets?

Comment: @E.D. You upcast the spell.  "At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, you can target one additional creature for each slot level above 2nd."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Your ruling is correct.

Your ruling is correct. Invisibility states the circumstances that end the condition. Receiving Damage does not end the condition.

*[Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility)* (PHB 243):

> A creature you touch becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything
>   the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on
>   the target’s person. The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts
>   a spell.

Also see Invisible (PHB 291).

[Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) (PHB 203):

> Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn't interfere with
>   concentration. The following factors can break concentration:
>
> Taking damage. Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on
>   a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your
>   concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever
>   number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an
>   arrow and a dragon's breath, you make a separate saving throw for each
>   source of damage.

You would have to take damage for damage to interact with your concentration spell. You do not take damage (or activate any of the other triggers that break concentration), so your concentration holds, and you don't have to make a check to maintain your concentration.

Comment: Also, there is some mono-target damaging spells requiring concentration (ie. [Phantasmal Killer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantasmal-killer)) so it would be weird to have to roll to maintain the spell against its own effect.

Answer (score 22):

### Your interpretation is correct

See the [rules](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells#toc_22) on concentration:

> Whenever **you** take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your Concentration.

Emphasis mine; you roll when you take damage yourself. Doesn't matter who the recipient of the spell is, only damaging the caster can break it.